# Laravel dropdownchecklist

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropdownchecklist

I creating a dropdownchecklist on my Modal, i send data with ajax to the modal

This is my modal view

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><img     src="<?php echo url().'/assets/buzzohero/front/img/close.png' ?>"></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Edit {{ $campaign->campaign_name }}<span></span></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <input type="hidden" name="campaign_id" value="{{ $campaign->id }}">
  <span>Choose the campaign's category</span>
  <select class="form-control" name="category[]" multiple="multiple" id="dropdown">
    <?php $parents = ""; ?>
    @foreach($categories as $result)
    <optgroup label="{{$result->name_category}}">
      @if(!empty($result->child))
      @foreach($result->child as $value)
        <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name_category}}</option>
      @endforeach
      @endif
    </optgroup>
    <?php $parents .= $result->id.","; ?>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  <input value="{{$parents}}">
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/dropdownchecklist/smoothness-1.8.13/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/dropdownchecklist/ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller.css') }}">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/dropdownchecklist/jquery-1.6.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/dropdownchecklist/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/dropdownchecklist/src/ui.dropdownchecklist.js') }}"></script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown").dropdownchecklist({ icon: {}, width: 400, maxDropHeight: 550 });
  });
</script>
```

the data that i send with ajax, i can receive it well, but the problem is the dropdownchecklist sometimes show up, and sometimes not show up data when it's clicked.. what happen?

I'm trying something different, i try to open inspect element at mozilla and let the inspect window open. I refresh the page and try the dropdownchecklist, it's always show and run great. what happen?

Answer (score 0):

I added set time out at my view script, for javascript load the script

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{{ URL::to('admin/campaign/edit') }}"+ '/' + id, 
    type: "GET"
  }).done(function(results){
    console.log(results);

    $("#edit-campaign-body").html(results);
  });
}, 100);
```

and it's work like a charm.